# Android telnet localhost 5554

Tags: android, gps, telnet

I have a little problem with Android GPS simulation through telnet. So that when I try to connect to Android device using **"telnet localhost 5554"** command it shows me the following messages and my application cannot take gps data from telnet:

```
telnet localhost 5554
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Android Console: type 'help' for a list of commands
OK
geo fix 32.234234 39.234234
OK
```

My Application gets GPS data from telnet as below:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapController = mapView.getController();

        mapView.setStreetView(true);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        mapController.setZoom(13);

        positionOverlay = new MyPositionOverlay();
        overlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        overlays.add(positionOverlay);

        String context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
        locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(context);

        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        userID="1";
        connect("http://10.0.2.2:8080/acil/gen/rest/user/"+userID+"/"+location.getLatitude()+"/"+location.getLongitude()+"/son");

        updateWithNewLocation(location);

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,    
                MINIMUM_UPDATE_INTERVAL, MINIMUM_UPDATE_DISTANCE,
                locationListener);

}
```

What is wrong? Or is there any other more efficient way to give gps data?

Comment: in Android code below location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);  code returns null and when I try location.getLatitude() or location.getLongitude() android application throws NullPointerException...

Comment: Ok, I've solved this problem...That was because I was not listening for location on telnet before getting this gps data - so I had to call locationListener before calling getLastKnownLocation() method! Sometimes small mistakes can cause big troubles, thanks for your time who have looked..